# In Python, what does this end=" " do in a print statement?

Tags: python-2.7, syntax, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get someone's code to run in Python.  This is the code...

```
def printGen(cols, rows, array, genNo):
os.system("cls")

print("Game of Life -- Generation " + str(genNo + 1))

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if array[i][j] == -1:
            print("#", end=" ")
        elif array[i][j] == 1:
            print(".", end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ", end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Python is telling me there is a syntax error at the '=' sign with this statement:

```
print("#", end=" ")
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting a syntax error, and more importantly, what the statement does?

Comment: Did you look at the [`print()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) yet?

Comment: You are trying to execute Python 3 code in Python 2. It can be made to work, but you'll need to add the documented `__future__` import first. Perhaps you want to switch to Python 3 instead.

Comment: There's two versions of Python: 2 and 3. And you are using the wrong one ;-)

Comment: Thanks Erik - I've been learning with v2; did not even consider v3.

Comment: @MichaelBHildebrand: if you are just starting with Python, I strongly recommend you learn Python 3. Python 2 is not receiving any new feature development and will reach end-of-life in under 4 years from now (only security fixes will be applied). All the exiting new things are going into Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of python.

Running your code under Python 2 yields:

```
>>> print("#", end=" ")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("#", end=" ")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Running your code under Python 3 yields:

```
>>> print("#", end=" ")
# >>>
```

For that code to work natively, you need to be using python 3.

Alternatively, to make it work under python 2:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("#", end=" ")
# >>>
```